# MySQL : FORCE INDEX vs USE INDEX

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm recently working on index optimization for MySQL table, i noticed that the 
 `FORCE INDEX` and `USE INDEX` almost serve same functionality, I would like to ask what is their different?

Comment: _"You can also use FORCE INDEX, which acts like USE INDEX (index_list) but with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the given indexes to find rows in the table."_ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: are they same or consume more resources?

Comment: If you use `USE INDEX` then you RECOMMEND optimizer to use this index, but it can use a table scan if optimizer _thinks_ it will be faster. If you use `FORCE INDEX` then you MAKE optimizer to use this index even if it _thinks_ a table scan is more efficient. Optimizer will use a table scan only if there is no way to use index to find rows.

Comment: @valex Post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Post my above comments as an answer:

If you use USE INDEX then you RECOMMEND optimizer to use this index, but it can use a table scan if optimizer thinks it will be faster. If you use FORCE INDEX then you MAKE optimizer to use this index even if it thinks a table scan is more efficient. Optimizer will use a table scan only if there is no way to use index to find rows.

[Index Hint Syntax:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html)

> You can also use FORCE INDEX, which acts like USE INDEX (index_list) but with 
>       the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, 
>       a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the given indexes 
>       to find rows in the table.